# WebGL won't render anything, what are the proper matrices?

Tags: graphics, 3d, webgl, projection

I'm trying to understand and learn WebGL and computer graphics from button up, that is why I started to work on my own little library for that. I've spent couple of days looking for right answer and I can't make it work.

I have column major matrices and I'm just trying to render basic triangle but for some reason no matter what I do after multiplification by perspective matrix my Z of vertex is always out of bounds.

I have an object set in space at position 0,0,0 with vertex positions of =

```
    [
        -0.5, -0.5, 0,
        0.5, -0.5, 0,
        0.5, 0.5, 0
    ]
```

my camera is set with 60 degree angle fov, aspect of `canvas.width / canvas.height`, near plane is `1/1000` and far plane of `50`. And is positioned on `(0,0,-10)` looking at my object.

On render time I supply to my vertex shader:

Unifrom Matrix4 u_model

```
[1 0 0 0
 0 1 0 0
 0 0 1 0
 0 0 0 1]
```

so basically Identity matrix

Uniform Matrix4 u_view

```
[-1  0  0  0
  0  1  0  0
  0  0 -1 -10
  0  0  0  1]
```

and Uniform Matrix4 u_projection

```
 0.0003282401348280833 0                      -0.3129605393123332  0
 0                     0.0003282401348280833  -0.3129605393123332  0
 0                     0                      -1.0000400008000159 -0.002000040000800016
 0                     0                      -1                   0
```

My Matrix model is

```
[n11, n12, n13, n14
 n21, n22, n23, n24,
 n31, n32, n33, n34,
 n41, n42, n43, n44 ]
```

my perspective matrix calculation :

```
static perspective(fov, aspect, near, far) {
    const r = fov * aspect;
    const l = -4;
    const t = r;
    const b = l;
    const matrix = new Matrix4();
    matrix.n11 = (2 * near) / (r - l);
    matrix.n12 = 0;
    matrix.n13 = (r+l)/(r-l);
    matrix.n14 = 0;
    matrix.n21 = 0;
    matrix.n22 = (2 * near) / (t - b);
    matrix.n23 = (t+b)/(t-b);
    matrix.n24 = 0;
    matrix.n31 = 0;
    matrix.n32 = 0;
    matrix.n33 = (near + far) / (near - far);
    matrix.n34 = (2 * near * far) / (near - far);
    matrix.n41 = 0;
    matrix.n42 = 0;
    matrix.n43 = -1;
    matrix.n44 = 0;
    return matrix;
}
```

my vertex shader

```
 this.vertexShaderScript =
        '\r\n' +
        'precision highp float;\r\n' +
        'uniform mat4 u_model;\r\n' +
        'uniform mat4 u_view;\r\n' +
        'uniform mat4 u_projection;\r\n' +
        'attribute vec3 a_position;\r\n' +
        'attribute vec4 a_color;\r\n' +
        'varying vec4 v_color;\r\n' +
        'void main(void) {\r\n' +
        '    v_color = a_color;\r\n' +
        '    gl_Position = u_projection * u_view *  u_model * vec4(a_position, 1.0);\r\n' +
        '}\r\n';
```

And fragment shader

```
 this.fragmentShaderScript = '\r\n' +
        'precision highp float;\r\n' +
        'varying vec4 v_color;\r\n' +
        'void main(void) {\r\n' +
        '    gl_FragColor = v_color;\r\n' +
        '}\r\n';
```

I have checked the view matrix, tryied to transpose projection, checked with spector js if I get matrices to shader and none of it worked. I also checked other answers but none works for me.

Which of the matrices is wrong?

rest of the code can be found on my github: https://github.com/barteq100/webgl

Comment: Where is your fragment shader? Have you tried drawing with no projection matrix? Where is your code for setting your matrix uniforms? Where is the code setting up your buffers and attributes? We can't tell what's wrong with your code unless you actually post it. What you've posted is not enough. You might find [these tutorials](https://webglfundamentals.org) helpful.

Comment: I can assure you everything else is fine but sure, look into rest of my code.

Comment: Posting a link your code offsite is off topic for Stack Overflow. You're required to make a **Minimal** and  **Complete**, Verifiable, Example and post that **In the quesiton itself** therefore I've voted to close. If you add an [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349790/128511) I'll be happy to undo my vote to close and take a look.

Comment: I have changed the question, is it alright now or should I add some more info, example point for example or js fiddle with example?

Comment: It would be best if you used a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to accomplish?

Your perspective function makes no sense to me. It appears to be based on the [`glFrustum` function from long deprecated OpenGL 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/opengl/glfrustum)

You'll notice that function takes 6 arguments, left, right, bottom, top, near far. Yours takes only 4 and the numbers you put in seem to be nonsense. Why is `l` which stands for left hardcoded to -4? Why do you think `r` should be `fov * aspect`?

Then you haven't shown the code that sets your matrixes so we have no idea how you're passing it. WebGL (and OpenGL) matrices are expected to be row major. Or to put it another way a translation matrix will be specified like this in JavaScript

```
const translationMatrix = [
  1, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 1, 0,
  x, y, z, 1,
];
```

The OpenGL spec calls each row of that matrix a column but by computer language standards they are rows. See https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-matrix-vs-math.html

If you want to learn WebGL perspective matrices [try this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-perspective.html). That article uses far more common perspective math.

In any case here is your perspective function. If I move the camera I can find a cube I'm drawing at the origin with some really strange perspective

```js
'use strict';

/* global twgl, m4, requestAnimationFrame, document */

class Matrix4 { }

function perspective(fov, aspect, near, far) {
  const r = fov * aspect;
  const l = -4;
  const t = r;
  const b = l;
  const matrix = new Matrix4();
  matrix.n11 = (2 * near) / (r - l);
  matrix.n12 = 0;
  matrix.n13 = (r+l)/(r-l);
  matrix.n14 = 0;
  matrix.n21 = 0;
  matrix.n22 = (2 * near) / (t - b);
  matrix.n23 = (t+b)/(t-b);
  matrix.n24 = 0;
  matrix.n31 = 0;
  matrix.n32 = 0;
  matrix.n33 = (near + far) / (near - far);
  matrix.n34 = (2 * near * far) / (near - far);
  matrix.n41 = 0;
  matrix.n42 = 0;
  matrix.n43 = -1;
  matrix.n44 = 0;
  return matrix;
}

function toMat(m) {
  return [
    m.n11, m.n21, m.n31, m.n41,
    m.n12, m.n22, m.n32, m.n42,
    m.n13, m.n23, m.n33, m.n43,
    m.n14, m.n24, m.n34, m.n44,
  ];
}

const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');

const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec2 texcoord;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 modelView;

varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main() {
  gl_Position = projection * modelView * position;
  v_normal = mat3(modelView) * normal;
  v_texcoord = texcoord;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision highp float;

varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
varying float v_modelId;

void main() {
  vec3 lightDirection = normalize(vec3(1, 2, -3));  // arbitrary light direction
  
  float l = dot(lightDirection, normalize(v_normal)) * .5 + .5;
  gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(0,1,0) * l, 1);
}
`;

// compile shader, link, look up locations
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

// make some vertex data
const bufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createCubeBufferInfo(gl, 1);

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;  // seconds
  
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);

  const fov = Math.PI * 0.25;
  const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 100;
  const projection = toMat(perspective(fov, aspect, near, far));
  
  const camera = m4.translation([0, 0, 1]);
  const view = m4.inverse(camera);
  let modelView = m4.rotateY(view, time);

  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  
  // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  
  // calls gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.uniformXXX
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    projection,
    modelView,
  });  
  
  // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

If I change the perspective function to something more traditional then it I'll get something more normal after moving the camera

```js
'use strict';

/* global twgl, m4, requestAnimationFrame, document */

class Matrix4 { }

function perspective(fov, aspect, near, far) {

  const f = Math.tan(Math.PI * 0.5 - 0.5 * fov);
  const rangeInv = 1.0 / (near - far);

  const matrix = new Matrix4();
  matrix.n11 = f / aspect;
  matrix.n12 = 0;
  matrix.n13 = 0;
  matrix.n14 = 0;
  matrix.n21 = 0;
  matrix.n22 = f;
  matrix.n23 = 0;
  matrix.n24 = 0;
  matrix.n31 = 0;
  matrix.n32 = 0;
  matrix.n33 = (near + far) * rangeInv;
  matrix.n34 = near * far * rangeInv * 2;
  matrix.n41 = 0;
  matrix.n42 = 0;
  matrix.n43 = -1;
  matrix.n44 = 0;
  return matrix;
}

function toMat(m) {
  return [
    m.n11, m.n21, m.n31, m.n41,
    m.n12, m.n22, m.n32, m.n42,
    m.n13, m.n23, m.n33, m.n43,
    m.n14, m.n24, m.n34, m.n44,
  ];
}

const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');

const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec2 texcoord;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 modelView;

varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main() {
  gl_Position = projection * modelView * position;
  v_normal = mat3(modelView) * normal;
  v_texcoord = texcoord;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision highp float;

varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
varying float v_modelId;

void main() {
  vec3 lightDirection = normalize(vec3(1, 2, -3));  // arbitrary light direction
  
  float l = dot(lightDirection, normalize(v_normal)) * .5 + .5;
  gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(0,1,0) * l, 1);
}
`;

// compile shader, link, look up locations
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

// make some vertex data
const bufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createCubeBufferInfo(gl, 1);

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;  // seconds
  
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);

  const fov = Math.PI * 0.25;
  const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 100;
  const projection = toMat(perspective(fov, aspect, near, far));
  
  const camera = m4.translation([0, 0, 3]);
  const view = m4.inverse(camera);
  let modelView = m4.rotateY(view, time);

  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  
  // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  
  // calls gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.uniformXXX
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    projection,
    modelView,
  });  
  
  // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

If you want to keep the same perspective math (ie, use the matrix from `glFrustum` linked above) then these are the values you need for `l`, `r`, `t`, `b`

```
  const t = near * Math.tan(0.5 * fov);
  const b = -t;
  const r = t * aspect;
  const l = -r;
```

```js
'use strict';

/* global twgl, m4, requestAnimationFrame, document */

class Matrix4 { }

function perspective(fov, aspect, near, far) {

  const t = near * Math.tan(0.5 * fov);
  const b = -t;
  const r = t * aspect;
  const l = -r;
  
  const matrix = new Matrix4();
  matrix.n11 = (2 * near) / (r - l);
  matrix.n12 = 0;
  matrix.n13 = (r+l)/(r-l);
  matrix.n14 = 0;
  matrix.n21 = 0;
  matrix.n22 = (2 * near) / (t - b);
  matrix.n23 = (t+b)/(t-b);
  matrix.n24 = 0;
  matrix.n31 = 0;
  matrix.n32 = 0;
  matrix.n33 = (near + far) / (near - far);
  matrix.n34 = (2 * near * far) / (near - far);
  matrix.n41 = 0;
  matrix.n42 = 0;
  matrix.n43 = -1;
  matrix.n44 = 0;
  return matrix;
}

function toMat(m) {
  return [
    m.n11, m.n21, m.n31, m.n41,
    m.n12, m.n22, m.n32, m.n42,
    m.n13, m.n23, m.n33, m.n43,
    m.n14, m.n24, m.n34, m.n44,
  ];
}

const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');

const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec2 texcoord;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 modelView;

varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main() {
  gl_Position = projection * modelView * position;
  v_normal = mat3(modelView) * normal;
  v_texcoord = texcoord;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision highp float;

varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
varying float v_modelId;

void main() {
  vec3 lightDirection = normalize(vec3(1, 2, -3));  // arbitrary light direction
  
  float l = dot(lightDirection, normalize(v_normal)) * .5 + .5;
  gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(0,1,0) * l, 1);
}
`;

// compile shader, link, look up locations
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

// make some vertex data
const bufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createCubeBufferInfo(gl, 1);

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;  // seconds
  
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);

  const fov = Math.PI * 0.25;
  const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 100;
  const projection = toMat(perspective(fov, aspect, near, far));
  
  const camera = m4.translation([0, 0, 3]);
  const view = m4.inverse(camera);
  let modelView = m4.rotateY(view, time);

  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  
  // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  
  // calls gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.uniformXXX
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    projection,
    modelView,
  });  
  
  // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: You just blew my mind. Now I understand that I had matrices complately reversed, using column major instead of row major. I will rewrite my matrices to row major and come back with and answer or new better question with snippets and all. Thank you.